# Binding data to a ListView with unknown number of columns

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm currently trying to populate a `ListView` with data imported by the user from a CSV file. As such, I know nothing of the number of columns nor their names at time of compilation, which is why I create a `GridView` and its columns in code and set it as the `ListView`'s `View` property.

Normally the `ListView` supports virtualization when the data is bound, but I can't bind it due to the aforementioned problem. And the fact remains that the view needs virtualization as I expect the user to be importing CSVs with tens of thousands of lines.

As I'm quite new to WPF and MVVM in general, I might be thinking about this problem the wrong way, but I haven't found any practical solution to my problem on here or anywhere. I'm thinking it might be the way I'm representing the data bound to the `GridView`, which is a custom class with the data being arrays, like this

```
public class DataSet
{
    public double[] Data { get; private set; }
    public double[] Targets { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

and binding that in code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDataSets; i++)
{
    gridView.Columns.Add( new GridViewColumn()
    {
        Header = "N" + (i + 1),
        Width = 40d,
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Targets[" + i + "]")
     });
}
```

A second `ListView` is used to display the `Data` array variable of the `DataSet` class, to avoid any confusion.

*EDIT*

This is the new ViewModel I'm currently using as the data provider of sorts. This model is bound to the `DataGrid`s ItemSource property, and when new data is inbound, a new DataTable is created from it and set to the ViewModels property

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged (string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); // error thrown here
    }

    private System.Data.DataTable data;
    public System.Data.DataTable Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            if (data != value)
            {
                data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MVVM concept is to let your view model handle the data that the client should see. You need to bind you xaml listView with the list from the viewmodel. Then update your list in the ViewModel and the view will be changed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your `ListView` for a `DataGrid` and use its [AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Also, any formatting you need to do to your data collection, do it in your ViewModel before consuming it from the View.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" />
```

You don't need to define your columns anywhere, they'll be auto-generated based on the columns of your DataTable. And with the last two properties, you activate virtualization so your RAM and processor don't get clogged.

**EDIT** - Make sure your DataGrid uses its own ScrollViewer. If you put it inside another ScrollViewer or inside a StackPanel, it won't be able to virtualize correctly.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement that, but I ended up creating a custom model for the data, with a datatable as the source for the view. No luck tho, the app still hangs and chugs up all the RAM when trying to display the list.

Comment: What are you doing to enforce virtualization? The `DataGrid` has properties for that, too: `EnableRowVirtualization` and `EnableColumnVirtualization`

Comment: Since the `DataGrid` didn't have a View property, I put a `GridView` in it and reference that from code instead, creating columns directly. This seems to have done something, as now the app freezes instead for just a few seconds before the new ViewModel I created throws an error: `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.` I'll update the question with the code of the ViewModel

Comment: You don't need a View for the DataGrid, it has a single view with rows and columns. The rows correspond to the `Items`/`ItemsSource`, and the columns can be either auto-generated using the property I mentioned, or defined through the `Columns` property. `AutoGenerateColumns` creates one column for each property of its items.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. I did as according to your sample, now the error disappears, but I'm back to the RAM shooting through the roof. One thing that just occured to me, _and I'm sorry for not mentioning this earlier_ but I've styled the entire app with MahApps MetroUI. I'll try it without this and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83771/discussion-between-stalem-and-almulo).

Comment: Maybe virtualization is not working because of how your screen is being layouted... Is your DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer or a StackPanel?